# Not Exactly one of the Fourteen - A simple riddle about the servant of ruin

Tags: riddle

**Not Exactly one of the Fourteen**

> I am ruin's servant. My name is well known.
>   Because you're unobservant. Your frustration has grown.
>   My opposite's opposite is wrath, though I am certainly not.
>   Reflecting my brother on the path. I am his heart subjected to rot.
>   You leave the page all the same and I laugh to myself with glee.
>   You'll not learn my name because you are me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Impatience

Because

> An antonym for wrath is patience, if you leave the page you won't solve the riddle because you are impatient. Impatience can be described as ruin's servant. Your heart (passion) for something can be rotted by being impatient.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right in front of us!

> Well Known

because

> "My name is well known. Because you're unobservant. Your frustration has grown."

Comment: Good eye, but how does it fit the rest of the riddle?